# Replace embedded vlc

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, vlc, sox

On my website I used embedded vlc to play some audio files but now this not supported by firefox or chrome. I can not use html5 because of some codecs. The files were generated with Android AMR codecs.

What should I use?

I would probably have to convert but I couldn't configure sox with AMR

Comment: which codecs fail on html5 ?  doc at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: The codec is AMR. I tried to convert the files with sox but I could not add amr support for sox. I am not sure if you can play arm now on a website, you probably have to convert it.